# javascript object value to string conversion

Tags: javascript

I am getting the value of input using javascript using below code.

```
var name=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
```

Getting output like rk-chaitu.I want to split this output using reg expression.

Now my question is how to convert name object to String?

Regards,

Chaitu

Comment: The DOM element's `value` should already be a string. Is it something else for you?

Comment: Hans Engel:when i am trying to split like name.split("-").It is saying object property not supported.

Comment: Add a line below the `name` declaration: `alert(typeof name);`. What does that show if you reload the page?

Comment: Was just typing that, Hans.  Well done.  :-)

Comment: If you get `rk-chaitu`, then `name` is not an object. Objects will generate `[object Object]` by default. So you get a string. Please post more of your code, maybe the error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` should already be a string. You can directly use `name.split(separator)`.

EDIT: I see you have added information. Can you post more code? Perhaps the error comes from something else.

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute should already be a String.